# How to see activity logs on a Linux PC?

Tags: linux, security, logging

I want to find out everything possible about how the PC was used in the past few days. Like who logged in, for how long was the PC was locked and any other information about user activity that is logged on the PC.

I know that last command can be used to find out who was logged in and for how long. Any other information that can be found out.

Answer (score 21):

The [`last`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/last) command will show user logins, logouts, system reboots and run level changes.

The [`lastlog`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lastlog) command "reports the most recent login of all users".

The file [`/etc/syslog.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf) will show how your log files are configured. For example, it may show that `auth` and `authpriv.*` facilities are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`. In other cases, such as Ubuntu, look at [`/etc/rsyslog.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf) and the files in `/etc/rsyslog.d` for this information.

Your log files will probably be rotated, so in addition to looking at files such as `/var/log/auth.log`, you may need to look in their older counterparts such as `/var/log/auth.log.1` and `/var/log/auth.log.n.gz` (using [`zcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zcat)) where "n" could be any integer depending on how your rotation is set up.

Although the files can be manipulated by the users, sometimes you can look at ones such as `~username/.bash_history`. Even files like `~username/.lesshst` can have useful information if you really need to dig deep.

Comment: The last paragraph is useful, I used **history -E** or **history -i** and got the datetime stamp, not unixtime as in the .bash-history. Regarding .lesshst, there seem to be no .morehst. But more is still used.

Answer (score 3):

an insteresting way to see all activity in one shot.

`egrep -r '(login|attempt|auth|success):' /var/log`

you can change keywords (login|attempt|auth|success) with suitable ones according to your linux box. to add more use long pipe in paranthesis.

Comment: `zgrep -e '(login|attempt|auth|success):' /var/log/*` to handle gzipped files.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the syslog messages in /var/log/* there is alot of good info there about what has been going on on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Beside all great answers here, it might be useful to also check shell history of all users (if for example admin checks if some failure wasn't caused by one of them). This could be checked in files like .bash_history / .zsh_history / .python_history with command:

```sh
sudo find / -name ".*_history" | sudo xargs tail -n 100
```

Note: Those files could be easily tampered by users

Answer (score -1):

Just add below line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
local3.*     /var/log/user-activity.log
```